# Hacer suma a valores de una tabla clave,valor sql

Tags: sql, oracle

tengo un problema y necesito de su ayuda para poder resolverlo.

Tengo una tabla llamada cumplimiento_variables en el cual dentro de sus columnas tiene 2 especificamente que son clave-valor, ejemplo:

```
CUMPLIMIENTO_VARIABLES
=========================================
CLAVE            VALOR         ID_REGISTRO
=========================================
ponderado        1                   1
clave1           Gerencia            1
clave2           1183                1
ponderado        4                   2
clave1           Gerencia            2
clave2           1183                2
ponderado        2                   3
clave1           Gerencia            3
clave2           1289                3
ponderado        1                   4
clave1           Gerencia 2          4
clave2           1662                4
```

En la tabla tenemos la columna "clave" que es el nombre y su valor correspondiente en la columna "valor". Para aclaración el "id_registro" corresponde a una fila especifica.

Tengo que obtener una agrupación entre los valores de "clave1" y "clave2" y asi poder aplicar SUM o COUNT a la clave "ponderado".

Ademas debe ser por clave y valores específicos por ejemplo Gerencia

```
Ejemplo de salida
=======================
clave1     clave2    SUMA ponderador
Gerencia   1183         6
Gerencia   1289         2
```

Entendiendo que la para poder agrupar debe ser con el valor de las claves

Tengo la siguiente Query, pero me esta retornando todos los valores y no esta generando la agrupación por valores como la necesito

```
    select 
    
    clave, 
    valor,
    id_registro
    from cumplimiento_variables cv
    where 
    upper(clave) IN (upper(trim('ponderado')), upper(trim('clave1')), upper(trim('clave2')))            
    and EXISTS(
        select
        1
        from cumplimiento_variables
        where
        upper(valor) IN (upper('Gerencia'))
        and upper(clave) = (upper(trim('clave1')))
        and id_registro = cv.id_registro
        and exists(
           select
            1
            from cumplimiento_variables
            where
            upper(valor) IN (upper('1183'), upper('1289'))
            and upper(clave) = (upper(trim('clave2')))
            and id_registro = cv.id_registro
            
        )
    ) 
 
    group by id_registro,valor,nombre
    order by id_registro;
```

Necesito ayuda, muchas gracias por el apoyo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo primero que tienes que hacer, es reorganizar la tabla para poder utilizarla correctamente. Esto se hace con un PIVOT o con agregados condicionales.

```
SELECT MAX( CASE WHEN CLAVE = 'clave1' THEN VALOR END) AS clave1
      ,MAX( CASE WHEN CLAVE = 'clave2' THEN VALOR END) AS clave2
      ,SUM( CASE WHEN CLAVE = 'ponderado' THEN TRY_CAST( VALOR AS int) END) AS ponderado
FROM CUMPLIMIENTO_VARIABLES
GROUP BY ID_REGISTRO;
```

Una vez teniendo esa estructura, podemos hacer la suma sin problema, usandola como una tabla derivada (subconsulta).

```
SELECT t.clave1
      ,t.clave2
      ,SUM(t.ponderado)
FROM( 
    SELECT MAX( CASE WHEN CLAVE = 'clave1' THEN VALOR END) AS clave1
          ,MAX( CASE WHEN CLAVE = 'clave2' THEN VALOR END) AS clave2
          ,SUM( CASE WHEN CLAVE = 'ponderado' THEN TRY_CAST( VALOR AS int) END) AS ponderado
    FROM CUMPLIMIENTO_VARIABLES
    GROUP BY ID_REGISTRO
    --HAVING MAX( CASE WHEN CLAVE = 'clave1' THEN VALOR END) = 'Alguna clave' --opción 1
    ) t
--WHERE clave1 = 'Alguna clave' --opción 2
GROUP BY t.clave1
        ,t.clave2;
```

Agregué las clausulas `HAVING` y `WHERE` que puedes usar para seleccionar un conjunto específico de datos. Sin embargo, es posible que puedas reducir el costo de la consulta obteniendo lo `ID_REGISTRO` necesarios antes de agrupar.

```
SELECT t.clave1
      ,t.clave2
      ,SUM(t.ponderado)
FROM( 
    SELECT MAX( CASE WHEN CLAVE = 'clave1' THEN VALOR END) AS clave1
          ,MAX( CASE WHEN CLAVE = 'clave2' THEN VALOR END) AS clave2
          ,SUM( CASE WHEN CLAVE = 'ponderado' THEN TRY_CAST( VALOR AS int) END) AS ponderado
    FROM CUMPLIMIENTO_VARIABLES
    WHERE ID_REGISTRO IN( SELECT ID_REGISTRO 
                            FROM CUMPLIMIENTO_VARIABLES 
                            WHERE CLAVE = 'clave1' 
                            AND VALOR = 'Alguna clave')
    GROUP BY ID_REGISTRO
    ) t
GROUP BY t.clave1
        ,t.clave2;
```

Comment: creo esta bien lo que comentas, pero me olvidé mencionar que debo seleccionar un conjunto especifico de datos (La tabla de ejemplo puede contener mas valores de clave y valor)

Comment: Edité la respuesta para agregar las formas de limitar los datos a un conjunto específico. Utilicé clave1 como forma de limitar los datos, pero espero que con eso puedas hacerlo mediante cualquier clave.

Comment: excelente! muchas gracias funcionó